# Looping through JSON array from an API, can get all results or none result, no luck with loops, using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, api

I'm just trying something new out to get skills more up to date, and am a bit stumped on this jQuery API response. I have all of the results going to console fine, I have them displaying on an html file, but all together as one. I want to put a break between each word (it's [Words API][1] and I'm stuck. I usually use PHP, but well, it's not practical for what I'm planning. Here is the code, and I'll show the best I can in results. Thank you!

```
   <div id="div1">
    // This is where it shows up as "unmitigated,butcherly,crimson,gory,homicidal,internecine"        
     </div>
   <script>  
const settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com/words/bloody/similarTo",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
    "x-rapidapi-key": "<my key>",
    "x-rapidapi-host": "<host>"
    }
 };

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
      $("#div1").html(response.similarTo + " "); // This puts a comma between each word, but no spacing, when I want a line break. I need to be able to customize results, make them links, add styles, etc.
});
```

Thank you so much! Only 3 more weeks of strict "stay at home" Covid19 orders. I'm learning a lot!

Comment: Hi, can you show output of `response` ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a text string in `response.similarTo` containing a mess of comma-separated words.

You can process them like this. Split breaks them at commas.  The rest of this code formats them into an HTML list and displays them.

```js
const results = []
const words = response.similarTo.split(',')
for (const word of words) {
  /* do what you will with each word in turn, for example... */
  results.push('<li>' + word + '</li>')
}
$("#div1").html('<ol>' + results.join('') + '</ol>')
```

Comment: It's working in console, but I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: response.similarTo.split is not a function" on that line unfortunately. I'm looking around for some fixes, still trying. Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: Your TypeError means `response.similarTo` is not a string: it doesn't have the `.split()` method. Do `console.log(response)`, examine the `response` object, and make sure you understand its contents.